# Xcode 9 can't open Info.plist when adding Localization to it

Tags: xcode

I can't run a project when adding Localization to Info.plist. Xcode 9 is saying:

[image]

And there is "R" icon next to Info.plist (Base) like this:

[image]

It is probably because of the fact that when adding Localization, folder structure is changing and info.plist is moved to Base.lproj folder and en.lproj folder but Xcode in "Build settings" is still indicating on old directory such as:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to not localize info plist, instead that you can add InfoPlist.strings file and localize this string file, in the file you can use info.plist keys for example

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Name of your app";
"NSCameraUsageDescription" = "Description";
```

from [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-102276)